# Reading value from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

[image]

```
$filepath = "C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\Tangent.xlsx"
$sheetname = "sheet"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$WorkBook.sheets | Select-Object -Property Name
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($sheetname)
$myObj = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    john  = $WorkSheet.Range("B1").Text
    Rebel = $WorkSheet.Range("B2").Text
    MArk  = $WorkSheet.Range("B3").Text
    Susan = $WorkSheet.Range("B4").Text
    Patty = $WorkSheet.Range("B5").Text
}
```

I have hardcoded all the names into the code which is a weird way of doing it. I want it to read from the Excel directing using command. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty hashtable and fill it as you iterate over the rows in your Excel sheet, then create the object.

```
$ht = @{}
$i = 1
while ($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text) {
    $ht[$WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 1).Text] = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($i, 2).Text
    $i++
}
$obj = [PSCustomObject]$ht
```

Untested, as I don't have Excel at hand here.